# What is the different between file with Selinux Context and without Selinux Context?

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux, selinux

Good day,

Today I compare file permission of 2 environment. Found that 1 of it having the dot  at the end of the permission, but another environment no have.

```
Environment 1 (with Selinux Context):
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin admin    69409 Dec  5  2018 activation-1.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin admin   445288 Dec  5  2018 antlr-2.7.7.jar

Environment 2 (without Selinux Context):
-rwxr--r--  1 admin admin    69409 Dec  5  2018 activation-1.1.1.jar
-rwxr--r--  1 admin admin   445288 Dec  5  2018 antlr-2.7.7.jar
```

After google, found that the dot is referring to `Selinux Context`, However, I am not really understand what is the `Selinux Context` use after reading on some article. Since we already have the `linux` permission `-rw-rw-r--`, then what is the use of the dot (Selinux Context) ?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

The information about Selinux context is obtained by adding -Z option to ls:

```
# ls -lZ /
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:boot_t:s0      boot
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:device_t:s0    dev
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       etc
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 home
...
```

Here is a short introduction that may help you understand some basics about Selinux : https://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/tip/SELinux-tutorial-Introduction-to-Linux-kernel-security